# Kinect modification kit for making turtlebot like robot?

Tags: kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am making the turtlebot from scratch since I already have the irobot create and the kinect sensor. I am confused about the kinect modification kit to power the kinect. How to make one? I have the kinect with an AC adapter. Do I need to modify the Adapter cable part? I cannot find any detailed information on how to make the cable. PS I am not using the Xbox kinect , but the educational kinect that windows sell. Please , if some one can provide detailed information would be helpful.

Thanks
Ankit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43959/kinect-modification-kit-for-making-turtlebot-like-robot?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about the windows kinect, but for the normal one it is quite easy.

Just clip the cable that runs from the AC adapter to the Y-connector. There should be two cables inside (brown and white, if I remember correclty). Those should be powered by 12V from your robot.

The best way to ensure that is the case and that the polarity is correct independent on cable colors, I'd suggest measuring the power on the clipped AC cable first.

Also, there is a [detailed tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20Kinect%20to%20an%20iRobot%20Create) that describes this.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-09-17**:
Thanks for your reply, in the detailed tutorial that you mentioned , they built a 12 V regulated power supply. I will use the turtlebot board with gyro, it says that the board generates regulated power for the kinect which draws power from the create. So do I still need to make the regulator?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-17**:
If they provide 12V regulated power, then you can use those. I'm sure there are specs for the boards available. In that case, you only need to connect the kinect power cable with the correct plug.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-09-17**:
This question may also help: http://answers.ros.org/question/43830/kinect-and-turtlebot-and-xbox/

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-09-17**:
thanks a lot ryan .. that answered everything..